# FIrefox - Cannot access multiple websites

Tags: firefox, internet

(Ubuntu 14.04) - Firefox Issue.

Hi,

Recently installed Ubuntu as my main OS and I'm having trouble accessing two websites, I may be missing something small and the obvious here so include information no matter how small, thanks.

(1) Firefox - E4 Player;

Video will not load, have typed "about:config" in web browser URL and "javascript.enabled" is set to true and not highlighted in bold.

Have not attempted to install any other plugins or attempted anything else.

(2) https://hre.ceridianhre.com/mandslive/marksandspencer.aspx

It's the work page for M&S, it says "Error - This functionality is not currently supported on your browser or device". I'm not sure if this requires an external plugin, updated plugin or wont work all together?

It's not the be all and end all as I can access it at work but ideally needs to be accessible from home.

Thankyou for reading and any help provided.

Comment: [Work Around] - M&S Website can be accessed via (will still give error message when logged out); https://www.ceridianhre.com/Portal/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fPortal

E4 Player still will not play episodes or videos, just loads with a circle in  middle of screen.